Looking for a 50~ year-old horror film about a cave filled with flying demons
I'm looking for a film that was produced in either the 1950s or the 1960s. My mom wants to recommend to me the "scariest film (she) and (her) family had ever seen", but she cannot remember the title. I'll describe everything she can relay.
The plot centers around a group of young adults who venture into a cave and find relics that eventually turn out to be the skeletons of demons, which systematically kill off members of the party. By the end of the film, there are two survivors who almost escape from the cave when one of them is snagged by a demon and dragged back into the abyss. The final survivor flags down a car, (perhaps a Rambler), which breaks down.
The final scene may include the driver of the vehicle not believing the survivor and going into the cave, saying that it was okay.
Additionally, my mom says the demons could fly and were stop-motion animated in the same vein as The Seventh Voyage of Sinbad. Also, the film was in color.

The interesting thing is that the two newer movies you mentioned do sound and look A LOT like what I'm looking for, only this one would have been from the 50s or 60s. Damn, I can't find if they were inspired by something older. Would you know, Arianna?

I would post this in a comment, but my rep isn't high enough yet:
Sounds similar to The Gargoyles from the '70s.



They find skeletons and there are flying "demons" (gargoyles) in a cave. That said, the ending doesn't quite match, and the whole movie isn't in the cave. (And it's from the '70s.)

I showed my mom your answer and she said it's unfortunately not a match. However, I do see the similarities. I wonder how obscure the film is that my mom and uncle watched...

"Equinox"(1970)?
There are young adults, they're in a cave at one point, and towards the end one of them is pulled back through a dimensional portal. The one survivor is attacked by a flying demon, but makes it to the road where I think he gets attacked by a driverless truck.

Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, and/or adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found. I hope you enjoy participating.
